# How can you round up a number and display it as a percentage?

Tags: c#

I'm a bit rusty on my mathematics so I hope someone can help me.  Using the code below I would like to do the following: Depending on the amount of memory installed, I would like to display the percentage of available memory and not how much is left in megabytes.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string memory;
    int mem;
    memory = GetTotalMemoryInBytes().ToString();
    mem = Convert.ToInt32(memory);
    mem = mem / 1048576; 
    progressBar2.Maximum = mem;
    progressBar2.Value = mem - (int)(performanceCounter2.NextValue());
    label2.Text = "Available Memory: " + (int)(performanceCounter2.NextValue()) + "Mb"; 


}

//using Microsoft visual dll reference in c#
static ulong GetTotalMemoryInBytes()
{
    return new Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo().TotalPhysicalMemory;
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you fetch the total memory, convert it to a string, then convert the string back to a number?

Comment: Hi Marc...I'm a newbie to c# hence my bad skills :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(Available memory / Total memory) * 100` will be your percentage.

```
double percent = ((performanceCounter2.NextValue() * 1.0) / mem) * 100;
label2.Text = "Available Memory: " + percent;
```

Comment: Hi rohit89...Thanks for this explanation of the code! Worked perfectly.  How do I round it up so it doesn't show anything after the decimal point? Thanks

Comment: `Math.Ceiling(percent)` will round up.

Answer (score 2):

To get a percentage, you use: `part/total * 100`, eg:

```
var Info = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices.ComputerInfo();

var PercentAvailable = Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory*1.0/Info.TotalPhysicalMemory * 100;
var PercentLeft = 100 - PercentAvailable;

// or alternatively:
var PercentLeft = (1 - Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory*1.0/Info.TotalPhysicalMemory) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

`mem / memory`  would be the percentage of used memory. To  get the available memory percentage, its 1 minus the result of that. But likely need a `double` for that.

Answer (score 0):

For most new machines, the total memory in bytes is at least 2GB. This does not fit into an Int32, so you won't work. Since you want to round up, you should use Math.Ceiling.

```
ulong total = My.Computer.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory;
ulong available = My.Computer.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory;
int pctAvailable = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)available * 100 / total);
int pctUsed = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(total - available) * 100 / total);
```